# enabling the lambda expression

Tags: java, java-8

In the program like

```
entities.stream().filter(m->m.getId()==id).findAny().get();
```

where `entities` is a `List`. After setting all the libraries and other SDKs  to Java 8. we are getting the error as:

```
use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions
```

Comment: How do you compile your code? Do you use an IDE?

Comment: Configure your pom.xml with source code level 8.

Comment: Yes,We are using intelij13.1

Comment: Check the language level for the project and if you're still getting problems each module.  It's possible to use Java 8 SDK and have the language level set to Java 7

Answer (score 30):

This is how solved my problem by adding the below plugin settings in my parent POM file.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```